# How to return(true/false) in ternary operators in jQuery/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to use return in ternary operator in jQuery?

```
myfunc: function() {
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        (6 == i) ? Do_This_and_This : return true;
    }
    //Error: Expected an operand: but found return false or true.
}
```

As per understanding return false will return back to function and breaks the loop and return true will work as continue which moves to next iteration.

Please validate understanding and provide solution for same. If there is another way to do it please suggest

**UPDATE**: My solution have big javascript and i have put small snippet for an instance that what it is doing. 
Like in for there are nested ifs` and nested ternary operators too. Lets give more snippet

```
myfunc: function() {
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ($.inArray(questionNumber, questions) > -1) ? ((Ra === "") ? Report= Report+"<tr><td>lakslak</td></tr>" : Report= Report+"<tr><td>lasaaakslak</td></tr>") : return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `myfunc: function(){ return false; }`???

Comment: You don't need conditional operator `return 6==i;`

Comment: @Satpal
Not working -> (1==1)? return (1!=1) : return (1==1);

Comment: Note that your `for` loop in the above is completely pointless, if you return where you've indicated, as you'll never reach the second iteration and (as @Bergi points out) the function will always return false (as 6 != 0).

Comment: @Satpal: You mean `return 6 != i;`.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder
Removed that line, helpers started refactoring snippet(which is not bad), but i felt that question text got ignored (especially 'IN' in question), so i added new snippet. Apology to all if anything offensive :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ternary operator is used on expressions, not on statements. You cannot put a `return` inside there - if you need to, use an `if` statement.

However, in your case can easily move the `return` outside:

```
return (6 == i) ? false : true;
```

Although you'd better do

```
return 6 != i;
```

---

For your updated code, I'd suggest to use

```
myfunc: function(){
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        if ($.inArray(questionNumber, questions) > -1)
            Report += (Ra==="") ? "<tr><td>lakslak</td></tr>" : "<tr><td>lasaaakslak</td></tr>";
            // or even
            //     += "<tr><td>"+(Ra===""?"lakslak":"lasaaakslak")+"</td></tr>";
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

You cannot use a conditional operator to return in one case but not the other, because `return` is a *statement*, and the conditional operator's operands are *expressions*, not statements. In JavaScript, you can use an expression where a statement is expected (it becomes an *ExpressionStatement*), but not vice-versa.

Comment: please understand the case.  Let me alter have following statement -> 

($.inArray(questionNumber, questions) > -1) ?
                        ((Ra==="") 
                            ? Report= Report+"<tr><td>lakslak</td></tr>"
                            :  Report= Report+"<tr><td>lasaaakslak</td></tr>")
                            : return true;

Comment: @fatherazrael: For that, use `if else` statements.

Comment: Can't i do that in ternary operator or suggest some way to do it?

Comment: @fatherazrael: He *has* suggested some way to do it: Use an `if` statement. You cannot use a conditional operator to trigger a return in one case but not in the other. The correct way to do that is to use `if`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
That's what i was looking for. So NO Alternative at all. It was already working in if. I was trying to refactor it using Ternary. But it is not possible. Thanks :)